# Expressing one as a sum of unique unit fractions whose denominators are increasing?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, fractions, egyptian-fractions

Given lower bound $N\in\mathbb N$, I am wondering if it is possible to express $1$ as a finite sum of unique unit fractions:

$$1=\frac{1}{n_1}+\frac{1}{n_2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n_k}$$

where $$N\le n_1<n_2<\cdots<n_k$$ for some $k$. One possible way I can think of is to repeatedly apply the identity $\frac1n=\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n(n+1)}$ to each of the terms in $1=\frac12+\frac13+\frac16$ until the desired condition is satisfied. But it is going to be hard to deal with collisions. Is there any efficient way to do this?